# Surface Area to Volume Ratio and Ice Baths

Tags: cell-biology, homework

Hi I was taking a practice test and stumbled across this question. I couldn't find information about this on the internet. Does anyone know why B is the answer? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of the image you posted. Images are not searchable, and are incompatible with screen readers for those with visual impairments.

Comment: At present there's insufficient information to determine if b. has merit, you would need to specify a timescale for measurement. As MattDMo says, please provide us with the full information.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: look up the square cube law in reference to heat.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. - I don't understand your comment either. Why do you need a timescale for measurement for this very basic Physics question? (Please answer me; when I ask you something in comments, I can't remember you ever answering me.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse This is the first time I recall you asking me anything. Apologies if I've been unintentionally rude. 1) We don't know what organisms are being referred to and if metabolic processes continue at ice-bath temperatures, 2) the square cube law's effect will be short-lived in such small organisms if their metabolism ceases for temperature/lack of energy as they will quickly asymptote to ambient temperature (timescale). We need more info to answer without making assumptions that may be unwarranted. That's it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I agree that a. c. and d. are impossible (assuming sphericity), but the practice-test is not a good one if the "correct" answer is only findable by exclusion of other answers - as opposed to findable by deduction from the information supplied, i.e. b. must be right, but there's only the evidence that the others are wrong to support it - e. or f. might be a better answer, but the nature of the multiple choice format is such that often it's not a good teaching aid.  I believe my concern was valid.

Comment: BTW. I had previously (mosquito hearing), but the comment was deleted. Just because something is common and seems "common sense" - doesn't inherently make it good quality. I've seen the same thing here (UK). Perhaps it might make a useful question on another site, [academia.se] or [psychology.se] regarding effective teaching/assessment.

Comment: Last comment on the issue, @ARogueAnt: I never said I liked the question or that it was good. I said it was common, and the fact that it's not a good question does not give validity to your request for more information. I use logic, and that it's common = it's good is a fallacy. It is common and it does not test all understanding; it tests the ability to deduce the correct answer using the information at hand, that's all it does. Well, also basic principles of Physics in this case.